# Threshold value in one-dimensional data

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have a list of similarity scores `similarity_scores` between two texts using some string matching method. I manually added `actual_value` to show if the texts were indeed similar. Is there any statistical way to find a threshold value over `similarity scrore`?

```
similarity_scores   actual_value
1.0 1
1.0 1
1.0 1
1.0 1
0.99    1
0.99    1
0.99    1
0.989   1
0.944   1
0.944   1
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   0
0.934   0
0.933   0
0.933   1
0.88    1
0.784   0
0.727   0
0.727   0
0.714   0
0.714   1
0.714   0
0.714   0
0.711   0
0.711   0
0.707   0
0.707   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your criteria. Can you explain your goal more clearly? How is the second column derived from the first?

Comment: Are you asking if there is some kind of statistical measure of whether two texts are "similar" or not, in a binary sense?  I don't think so - I don't see how that could be anything more than a subjective judgement call.

Comment: So basically you have N points representing prediction and actual class, and you want to choose threshold to minimize an error, right? In this case it's nothing more than optimization problem with a single parameter (threshold value). Choose optimization criteria (e.g. mean or errors or [mean of squared errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or simply count of misclassified examples) and run, say, gradient descent to minimize this criteria. Or just try several values and find what looks good - this is what I would do in practise :)

Comment: @Cyber, The second column has been created manually.

Comment: @user1140126 I got that part, but I guess my question was how? When did you enter `1` vs `0`? What was your criteria to choose?

Comment: @ffriend, You are right. Which algorithm is available for such optimization?

Comment: @Cyber, As I mentioned in the OP that the first column is the result of string matching algorithm. Then I go back manually to check if they are indeed similar or not. If they are similar, I write 1 else 0

Comment: Okay, so are you asking for an algorithm/metric to define if two strings are similar? Or once you have a score (assuming you already have such a function/algorithm), how to make the second column?

Comment: Ya thats right. I am trying to use the threshold found for the above data to apply on my actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way of determining how good a particular classification is for document retrieval is to use the [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) values. In your example, for a given threshold **[1]**:

**Precision** tells you what percentage of the documents above the threshold were manually tagged with a `1` value, or,

```
number of documents above the threshold tagged 1
------------------------------------------------
    number of documents above the threshold
```

**Recall** tells you what percentage of the documents tagged with a `1` were above the threshold:

```
number of documents above the threshold tagged 1
------------------------------------------------
         number of documents tagged 1
```

In the example you gave, you can compute these values for each possible threshold, but the only relevant ones are those in which we have transitions between sequences of zeros and ones, so I'll only look at those points:

```
1.0 1
1.0 1
1.0 1
1.0 1
0.99    1
0.99    1
0.99    1
0.989   1
0.944   1
0.944   1 TH=0.944 #1's=10; #0's=0
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   1
0.941   0 TH=0.941 #1's=14; #0's=1
0.934   0
0.933   0
0.933   1 TH=0.933 #1's=15; #0's=3
0.88    1 TH=0.880 #1's=16; #0's=3
0.784   0
0.727   0
0.727   0
0.714   0
0.714   1
0.714   0
0.714   0 TH=0.714 #1's=17; #0's=9
0.711   0
0.711   0
0.707   0
0.707   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
0.696   0
```

And the total number of documents tagged `1` is `17`.

Therefore, for these 5 possible thresholds `TH`, we have `precision` and `recall` as follows:

```
TH = 0.944
    precision = 10/10       = 1.000
    recall = 10/17          = 0.588
TH = 0.941
    precision = 14/15       = 0.933
    recall = 14/17          = 0.824
TH = 0.933
    precision = 15/18       = 0.833
    recall = 15/17          = 0.882
TH = 0.880
    precision = 16/19       = 0.842
    recall = 16/17          = 0.941
TH = 0.714
    precision = 17/26       = 0.654
    recall = 17/17          = 1.000
```

What you do with these values from here depends a great deal on your data and how sensitive the results should be to false negatives or false positives. For instance, if you want to make sure that you have as few false positives as possible, you would want to go with a threshold of `TH = 0.941` or even `TH = 0.944`.

If you want to balance precision and recall, you might want to go with `TH = 0.880` because both measures increase from the threshold above it and precision is much better than the threshold below it. This is a rather subjective way of doing this, but we can automate it to an extent by using an [F-measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_Score). In particular, I'll use the `F1-measure`, but you can find one that suits your data.

The `F1-measure` is defined as:

```
F1 = 2 * precision * recall
         ------------------
         precision + recall
```

Using the numbers above we get:

```
TH = 0.944   F1 = 2*1.000*0.588/1.000+0.588 = 0.741
TH = 0.941   F1 = 2*0.933*0.824/0.933+0.824 = 0.875
TH = 0.933   F1 = 2*0.833*0.882/0.833+0.882 = 0.857
TH = 0.880   F1 = 2*0.842*0.941/0.842+0.941 = 0.889
TH = 0.714   F1 = 2*0.654*1.000/0.654+1.000 = 0.791
```

As you can see, by the F1 measure, `TH=0.880` comes out on top with `TH=0.941` not too far behind, giving very similar results to manual inspection of the possible thresholds.

**[1]** To clarify, I define **threshold** such that similarity scores **greater than or equal to** the threshold are considered **above** the threshold and similarity scores **strictly less than** the threshold are considered **below**.